# Why does Invoke-SqlCommand not work outside Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell

I am running a script. But when trying to run it outside Powershell ISE it comes with the error "The term 'Invoke-SqlCommand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet".

The SQL module is importet via the script and in both cases the script is executed in the same user context. Any ideas?

[In Powershell ISE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEf0Q.jpg)

and

[In powershell CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cetx.jpg)

Comment: Are you using [this function](https://pastebin.com/tBK2Ugfm)?  If so, try dot-sourcing the script or module that defines `Invoke-SqlCommand`, or call `Import-Module xxxx`, where xxxx is the name of the module that defines it, or copy-paste the function directly into your script.  Otherwise, see the native `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlets provided by Microsoft in their sqlps and sqlserver modules.

Answer (score 0):

Think the mistake was placing function after mainscript. Rookie Mistake ;-)